# Drag and Drop doesn't work on newly copied files

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-files

**elementary OS 5.0 Juno**
**Files 4.1.7**

Drag on newly copied files doesn't seem to work and have to close and relaunch the Files application to get it back to working.

**Steps to reproduce:**

Copy a file and paste it anywhere else and try dragging it.

Tried with double tap on touchpad, holding right click and drag.

Comment: I could not reproduce this with v 4.1.7 using the operations you described and normal files or folders.  However, you should not raise this kind of thing here - it is not a question. You should raise bugs at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues.

Comment: @JeremyWootten So I figured out it was because I have disabled the single click to open the files/folders and was using double click to open. With this Modification I guess this will not be considered as a bug?

Comment: Yes, it is still a bug as Files supports both single-click and double-click modes at the moment.  However, I could not reproduce with either single or double click mode.  Make sure any bug report includes as much detail as possible about any non-default settings for Files, mouse or touchpad, as well as the source and destination folders and filetype.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem but using the right button to drag works (instead of the default left click).